# MifareClassic#get() throws NPE on Android 10 (but not on Android 8)

Tags: android, nfc, android-10.0

I have just migrated from Android 8 to 10, and my NFC test app now starts throwing an NPE whenever reading a Mifare tag. Other tags seem to work (specifically one supporting NfcV, NdefFormatable).

Stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1277): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'short android.os.Bundle.getShort(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime( 1277):    at android.nfc.tech.NfcA.<init>(NfcA.java:76)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1277):    at android.nfc.tech.NfcA.get(NfcA.java:62)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1277):    at android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic.<init>(MifareClassic.java:150)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1277):    at android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic.get(MifareClassic.java:140)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1277):    at myapp.nfc_reader.TagViewer.dumpTagData(TagViewer.java:201)
```

Upon receiving an NFC intent, the app does this:

```
Parcelable p = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
Tag tag = (Tag) p;
for (String tech : tag.getTechList()) {
    if (tech.equals(MifareClassic.class.getName())) {
        MifareClassic mifareTag = MifareClassic.get(tag);
        // more code here
    }
}
```

Apparently `Tag` has a non-public `Bundle` member, which is null on Android 10 and causes the NPE. This has worked on Android 8 (LineageOS 15.1) but fails on Android 10 (LineageOS 17.1; the device is a OnePlus One).

Is that a bug in the OS or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an OS Bug

This change looks suspect https://review.lineageos.org/c/LineageOS/android_frameworks_base/+/256596/5/core/java/android/nfc/tech/NfcA.java

First introduced in lineage-17.0 (Android 10 release)

why the code below has the useless `if` statement I've no idea that does nothing useful because `mSak` and `mAtqa` are reset using the stock Android code straight after the useless `if` and line 76 is in the useless `if`

```java
    public NfcA(Tag tag) throws RemoteException {
        super(tag, TagTechnology.NFC_A);
        Bundle extras;
        mSak = 0;
        if(tag.hasTech(TagTechnology.MIFARE_CLASSIC))
        {
            extras = tag.getTechExtras(TagTechnology.MIFARE_CLASSIC);
            mSak = extras.getShort(EXTRA_SAK);
        }
        extras = tag.getTechExtras(TagTechnology.NFC_A);
        mSak |= extras.getShort(EXTRA_SAK);
        mAtqa = extras.getByteArray(EXTRA_ATQA);
    }
```

this is not what is in stock Android https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/android10-release/core/java/android/nfc/tech/NfcA.java

[Following edited by another user]
This is fixed with this patch. https://review.lineageos.org/c/LineageOS/android_packages_apps_Nfc/+/306229

Comment: `mSak` is not reset but a bit-wise OR of the values reported from Mifare Classic extras and NfcA extras, and `mAtqa` is only ever set from NfcA extras. Dunno what this is supposed to do, but apparently I’ve hit a case where MifareClassic extras are null, which throws an NPE on the second line of the `if` block.

Comment: A yes missed the | in the diff, `mSak` is used to determine type and size of Mifrare Classic Card in MifareClassic.java and as the change that introduced it says "a new size for MIFARE Classic tags", all seem a bit of a strange change.

Comment: Odd… other handsets seem to have had a similar issue, the app from which I forked mine catches the exception, cleans up the `Tag` instance (see https://github.com/nadam/nfc-reader/blob/master/src/se/anyro/nfc_reader/TagViewer.java#L261) and retries—which works. Guess I’ll file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed with this patch.
https://review.lineageos.org/c/LineageOS/android_packages_apps_Nfc/+/306229
Dear OP please confirm.

Dear Super power users, if you plan to delete my answer then better justify why you are doing it. Otherwise, I will try again until OP accepts or resolves this.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. Since this is not really an answer in itself but more a piece of extra information for the previous answer, I would suggest you add this as a comment or an edit to that answer.

Comment: Dear @user149408, Thank you for pointing out that I can edit someone else's post. For completeness, I did try to add this as a comment. Unfortunately, due to my lack of 50 reputations I couldn't. Hence, I wrote a separate answer giving credit to Andrew as he pointed in the correct direction. Unfortunately, super power users simply deleted my post. I don't know if you can see them. Well, I am too old to be a noob & too old to understand the need for 50 reputations to comment. Just thought that sacrificing my slow laptop with many crashes to get my build tested was worth a blip in this thread.

Comment: lemme bump your rep then, 37 to go :-) yeah, the first 50 are the hardest, I remember

Comment: @user149408 Thank you very much :-)